# Append multikey Json array in php?

Tags: php, json, api

I am working on a simple API for a web server where you can set answers to querys with multiple querys tied to one answer.

Here is my code so far but I need a way to append queries (multikeys) to each question (value) and I'm not sure how to fit it together.

```
$question = urldecode($_GET["q"]);
$admin = urldecode($_GET["admin"]);
$answer = urldecode($_GET["answer"]);
$donext = urldecode($_GET["donext"]);

if ($admin == "password123") {
    $file = fopen("program.json", "a+") or die ("file not found");
    $json = file_get_contents('program.json');
    $data = json_decode($json, true);
    $keys = array($q1, $q2, $q3);  // need to append this with $q each time.
    $train = array_fill_keys($keys, '$a."+".$donext');
    //$data[$tagid] = $tagvalue; 
    $newjson = json_encode($data);
    file_put_contents('program.json', $newjson);
    fclose($file);
} else {
    $file = fopen("program.json", "a+") or die ("file not found");
    $json = file_get_contents('program.json');
    $data = json_decode($json, true);
    $a = $data->$q;
    $piece = explode('+', $a);
    $reply = $piece[0];
    $nextcontext = $piece[1];
    fclose($file);
    echo $reply;
    echo $donext;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by multikeys?

Comment: I mean Json where there is for example  a value with multiple keys that point to it.

Comment: You mean an arrays? Like `{key:{'val', 'val'}}`, or PHPs `$array[$key] = $val;`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to put multiple keys to the same value:

```
<?php
$questionkeys = array('hi','hey','yo');
$answervalue = "hello to you too";
$outputarray = array_fill_keys($questionkeys, $answervalue);
echo $outputarray;
?>
```